# PHP regex subroutine reference not working

Tags: php, regex

I have a simple regex like this:

```
@123(?:(?:(?P<test>[\s\S]*)456(?P<test1>(?P>test))789))@
```

It should match the following string fine:

```
123aaaa456bbbb789
```

But it doesn't.

But if I replace the subroutine reference with a direct copy of the regex:

```
@123(?:(?:(?P<test>[\s\S]*)456(?P<test1>[\s\S]*)789))@
```

Then it works perfectly fine.

I can't figure out why referencing the pattern by the group name isn't working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point here is that `[\s\S]*` is a `*` quantified subpattern that allows a regex engine to backtrack once the subsequent subpatterns fail to match, *but* the recursion calls in PCRE are *atomic*, i.e. there is no way for the engine to backtrack when it grabs any 0+ chars with `(?P>test)`, and that is why the pattern fails to match.

In short, `@123(?:(?:(?P<test>[\s\S]*)456(?P<test1>(?P>test))789))@` pattern can be re-written as

```
@123(?:(?:(?P<test>[\s\S]*)456(?P<test1>[\s\S]*+)789))@
                                              ^^
```

and as `[\s\S]*+` already matches `789`, the engine cannot backtrack to match `789` pattern part.

See [PCRE docs](https://pcre.org/pcre.txt):

> In  PCRE (like Python, but unlike Perl), a recursive subpattern call is always treated as an atomic group. That is, once it has matched some of the subject string, it is never re-entered, even if it contains untried alternatives and there is a subsequent matching failure.

No idea why they mention Python here since `re` does not support recursion (unless they meant the PyPi regex module).

If you are looking for a solution, you might use a `(?:(?!789)[\s\S])*` [tempered greedy token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30900794/tempered-greedy-token-what-is-different-about-placing-the-dot-before-the-negat) instead of `[\s\S]*`, it will only match any char if it does not start a `789` char sequence (so, no need to backtrack to accommodate for `789`):

```
123(?:(?:(?P<test>(?:(?!789)[\s\S])*)456(?P<test1>(?P>test))789))
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pyuAHi/1).

Comment: In this case regex `123(?:(?:(?P<test>\D*)456(?P<test1>(?P>test))789))` solves the problem

Comment: @splash58 Yes, because `\D*` does not match digits, but in case there is a digit between `456` and `789` and the match *is* expected, that cannot be a generic solution. A more appropriate (though not so efficient) is a [tempered greedy token solution](https://regex101.com/r/pyuAHi/1).

Comment: an interesting approach :)